# EmailJS calls callback twice

Tags: node.js, email

am using emailjs to send mails in nodejs but the problem is, the callback is called twice, output is:

```
mail test
sending status...

err { Error: no connection has been established
    at module.exports (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\error.js:33:14)
    at SMTP.send (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:377:5)
    at SMTP.command (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:414:8)
    at SMTP.helo (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:428:8)
    at ehlo (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:635:11)
    at caller (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:76:12)
    at command (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:507:5)
    at caller (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:76:12)
    at response (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:397:5)
    at caller (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\smtp.js:76:12) code: 6, smtp: undefined, previous: null }
message Message {
  attachments: [],
  alternative:
   { data: '<html>i <i>hope</i> this works! </html>',
     alternative: true,
     charset: 'utf-8',
     type: 'text/html',
     inline: true },
  header:
   { 'message-id': '<1535820394667.0.14872@Ali-pc>',
     date: 'Sat, 01 Sep 2018 19:46:34 +0300',
     from: 'portal@hudumakenya.go.ke',
     to: 'hamisi.yusuf@ekenya.co.ke',
     subject: '=?UTF-8?Q?testing_emailjs?=' },
  content: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  text: 'i hope this works' }
sending status...

err { Error: timedout while connecting to smtp server
    at module.exports (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\error.js:33:14)
    at TLSSocket.timedout (D:\tests\node_modules\emailjs\smtp\response.js:65:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:410:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5) code: 4, smtp: undefined, previous: null }
message Message {
  attachments: [],
  alternative:
   { data: '<html>i <i>hope</i> this works! </html>',
     alternative: true,
     charset: 'utf-8',
     type: 'text/html',
     inline: true },
  header:
   { 'message-id': '<1535820394667.0.14872@Ali-pc>',
     date: 'Sat, 01 Sep 2018 19:46:34 +0300',
     from: 'portal@hudumakenya.go.ke',
     to: 'hamisi.yusuf@ekenya.co.ke',
     subject: '=?UTF-8?Q?testing_emailjs?=' },
  content: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  text: 'i hope this works' }
```

and this is my code

```
var server  = email.server.connect({
    user:   "", 
    password:"", 
    host:   "", 
    tls: {ciphers: "SSLv3"},
    ssl: false,
    port: 587,
    authentication: [ 'LOGIN' ],
    // timeout: 20000
 });

 var message    = {
    text:   "i hope this works", 
    from:   "portal@hudumakenya.go.ke", 
    to:     "hamisi.yusuf@ekenya.co.ke",
    subject:    "testing emailjs",
    attachment: [
        {
            data: "<html>i <i>hope</i> this works! </html>",
            alternative: true
        }
    ] 
 };
 console.log('mail test');
 server.send(message, function(err, message) { 
     console.log('sending status...'); 
     console.log(); 
     console.log('err', err); 
     console.log('message', message);
});
```

the `console.log('mail test')` is just to check if the file is executed twice but turns out its called only once but the callback is called twice. Even more strange and confusing is the fact that even though its producing those errors, its still sending the email, can anyone help me out here because this is now driving me crazy, thanks.

**EDIT**

The package am using is [emailjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs)

Comment: which package you are using for email and what is your SMTP server?

Comment: @AtulAgrawal using emailjs package and for the smtp server, i guess its a microsoft one because i have just been given the credentials by the client and am not really sure which is it, but the credential worked when i try with C# without any issues

Comment: why you are not trying nodemailer in that case ?
https://nodemailer.com/about/

Comment: i started with nodemailer, but nodemailer isnt even connecting to the smtp server to begin with, it spits out this error  `{ Error: 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:
 code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }` (nodemailer)

Comment: @AtulAgrawal with nodemailer, i changed secure to false and it sent the email which is strange because am pretty sure i have tried that setting before and it failed

Comment: could you please give me your code?

Comment: That one i posted up there, is the code that i used with emailjs but never mind because it already worked with nodemailer @AtulAgrawal